# Select onChange Ajax get list of data from mysql database Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have 2 select input fields.

first select input field contains static data.

second select input field needs to be populated depending on first input field selected value.

## Below is my code

```
<select id="filter_type" name="filter_type" class="selectpicker form-control" style="width:30%;">
           <option value>Select Filter Type..</option>
           <option value="abc">Abc</option>
           <option value="def">Def</option>
           <option value="ghi">Ghi</option>
           <option value="jkl">Jkl</option>
</select>

<select id="search" name="search" class="selectpicker form-control" style="width:70%;" disabled="disabled">
       <option value>Select Filter type first..</option>
</select>
```

## Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#filter_type").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
console.log(id);
var dataString = 'id='+ id;
console.log(dataString);
$.ajax
({
type: "GET",
url: "{{url('/users/abc')}}",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(data)
{
  console.log(data); // I get error and success function does not execute
} 
});

});

});
</script>
```

## Controller

```
public function get_onchange_data(Request $request)
{
        if($id == 'abc')
        {
            $searches = Abc::select('field_name')->get();
            return response(view('/users/Def', compact('searches'))->render());
        }
}
```

I am unable to get returned ajax data.

I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/users/abc?id=year&_=1496176229318 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I think my check in if condition is wrong. I am considering $id as the value passed from dataString.

I don't know how to do this. Get the data, compare it with if condition and finally return array result of the data.

## Edited code

```
$("#filter_type").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
console.log("1:"+id);
var dataString = '{id:'+ id+'}';
console.log("2:"+dataString);
$.ajax
({
type: "GET",
url: "{{url('/users/abc')}}",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(data)
{
  console.log("3:"+data);
} 
});

});

public function get_search_data(Request $request)
{
    return response($request->input('id'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two/Three issues here:

1. You haven't defined `$id` in the context of your method. Access it via your request object `$request->input('id');`
2. Don't send your data as a string, send it as an object `data: {id: id}`
3. Always return a response. If the statement evaluates to false, the request will not be answered.

Comment: I am trying to return response as what I sent but I get empty response. this is what I hve in controller. return response($request->input('id'));  and I changed this var dataString = '{id:'+ id+'}'; as you said. On success I hve this: console.log("3:"+data);  so I know what is returned back I get only  3:

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you want to tell me.
Also dont make the payload a string. Make it an javascript object.

Comment: I hve updated my question with edit section. which has newly updated code as you suggested. I am not aware of js object. do you mean. data: {id : id}

Comment: Okay, it seems that you don't have a clue what is going on here. I suggest that your read the laravel docs on Request and Response, and also a tutorial on javascript ajax requests.
I'm certain you will find a good tutorial on laracasts for ajax requests response cycle.

Comment: I got it working. but the data is in this format : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...  I need to extract, loop and populate second select dropdown.